# How to get Authentication header to persist

Tags: python, django, http, authentication, cookies

I am trying to setup token based authentication in python. using Django/DRF. but this is more about http in general i think.

When users put in username/password I return to them their token via JSON.

The client then can post the token in HTTP Header for me to check.

My problem is I want the token to persist in the header automatically, just like cookies.
When the server says "set-cookie" to browser (Chrome/FF), the browser will automatically send up the cookie without me actually doing anything.  Is there something I can do with this token?

I have tried storing it in header: "Authorization", but the browser didn't return it.  Is there something like "Set-Authorization"?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, only cookies stored in browser persistently. All other headers are transient by HTTP protocol definition.